# When do Cloud Functions retry?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions

Having enabled **[retries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/retries)** for my Cloud Function, I am wondering what all the cases are that it will retry.

[This section](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/retries#use_catch_with_promises) seems contradictary to me. Hence, I assume that I do not understand it.
I thought that the following implies that the function that have "Retry on failure" enabled will also retry on fatal errors:

> Cloud Functions does not understand a fatal error that shouldn't be retried

However, what is the point of catching errors and using `Promise.reject` in that case?
I tried to use `Promise.reject` to cancel retries of my Cloud Function, however, that does not happen.

```
return Promise.reject(..) // will retry
throw Error() // will retry
```

Both will retry for a week if the function is not redeployed.
To me it seems like fatal errors **and** `Promise.reject` will **both** retry, however, the documentation says:

> you should modify your code accordingly if you support fatal errors

What is the point of [this section](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/retries#use_catch_with_promises) in the documentation and what should I really do now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud Functions will retry a function if it yields any sort of error at the end.  This includes a rejected promise, a thrown exception, or a timeout.

If you don't want a function to retry, then catch all errors, and return a successful promise.  If you know that an error will never go away for a future retry (for example, bad input values), then don't arrange for it to be retried. Otherwise, you will just be charged for all the retries that don't work.

The whole point of retries is to handle cases where there are temporary errors, such as network problems.  So, you should make sure that your function only yields an error for cases where it's expected that a function would eventually succeed some time in the future.

Feel free to use the "Send feedback" button on any page of documentation if you find that documentation to be confusing.

Comment: Well, only the last part addresses my question remotely, so I will make a guess: you say that the documentation is only "confusing" for me there? Could you explain what the documentation says if it is clear to you? That was the point of my question. Everything else is obvious and explained in the documentation.

Comment: I can't explain the documentation.  All I can explain is how I perceive the system to work.  If you have a question about the documentation, use the send feedback link.

Comment: I sent it as feedback via the feedback feature on the documentation page, however, I am not sure if I will get an *answer* this way. In the meantime, I can just wait for someone to *answer* my question here. Maybe there is someone who knows.

Comment: Well, you did get an answer here.  You asked "what is the point of catching errors and using Promise.reject?" and got an answer. You also asked "what should I do now?", and you got directed to the correct forum.

Comment: So what is the answer to "what is the point of catching errors and using `Promise.reject` in that case?"? To me it seemed like an error and `Promise.reject` are the same and you said the same thing, but you just said that it is the case. Nice that we agree. I was also not referring to your answer. Any input is fine and I am not trying to aggravate you, however, I am still exactly where I was before, that is what I meant with "someone to answer my question here".

Comment: I can't explain why the docs make that recommendation. I gave you my take above.

Comment: Does Cloud Function retry works also on cases of "The request was aborted because there was no available instance." (error 500)?

Comment: @ItsikBelson There are no retries for HTTP functions.  Clients have to retry any errors they see in the response, if that's the behavior they want.  There are only retries for background triggers.

Comment: Thanks @DougStevenson. For background triggers, does the retry fire also for the case there are no available instances?

Answer (score 0):

I think the code sample in the Google docs is simply wrong. I would suggest it should be:

```
return doFooAsync().catch(err => {
    if (isFatal(err)) {
        console.error(`Fatal error ${err}`);

        return true;
    }

    throw err;
});
```

If the error is fatal (you don't want to retry), log the error and return true (you do not need to `Promise.resolve(true)` as the framework will wrap the return value in a Promise. If the error is not fatal (you want to retry), just re-throw the error (again, `Promise.reject(err)` is redundant).